# Making an admin for my app

Tags: java, mysql, sql, javafx

So if an user has in the db, at the column admin 1 instead of 0, to load a different fxml file, in which the admin can do more stuff then a regular user.

This is the controller which is responsable for the login of the user, testing if the password and username are in the db.

PS More comments about how i tried to make a method down below.

```
public class LogareController implements Initializable {

LoginVerifier loginVerifier = new LoginVerifier();


   @FXML
   private TextField Numeutilzator;

   @FXML
   private PasswordField Parola;

   @FXML
   private Label Stare;






@Override
 public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {


  if (loginVerifier.Conexiune()) {
  Stare.setText("");
  } else {

  Stare.setText("Conexiune nereusita!");

  }

 }

 public void Autentificare (ActionEvent event) {
     try {
         if(loginVerifier.testaredate(Numeutilzator.getText(),         Parola.getText())) {
             Stare.setText("Autentificare reusita !");
             ((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow().hide();
                Stage st= new Stage();
            FXMLLoader loader= new FXMLLoader();
            Pane Pane =     loader.load(getClass().getResource("/LicentaApp/Meniu.fxml").openStream());

            Scene scene = new Scene(Pane);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("Style1212.css").toExternalForm());
            st.setScene(scene);
            st.show();

          }
     else { 
         Stare.setText("Nume de utilizator sau parola incorect");

     }




} catch (SQLException e) {





     e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
    }
         }
     @FXML
    public void Inregistrare(ActionEvent event) {
        try {
             ((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow().hide();
                    Stage PS= new Stage();
                FXMLLoader loader= new FXMLLoader();
                Pane Pane1 =     loader.load(getClass().getResource("/LicentaApp/InregistrareUser.fxml").openStream());
                Scene scena = new Scene(Pane1);
                scena.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("Style1212.css").toExternalForm());
            PS.setScene(scena);
            PS.show();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }



    }
// This is what I came up with, I know its bad, but I can't think of anything else, in this method I am trying to save the value of "Admin" from the table in a variable, which I can you to determen if the user has 0 or 1 at the admin, If he has 1 then a new fxml will be loaded for him, if he has 0 he is a 
regular user

public boolean admin(int admin) throws SQLException {
      ConectaredB ConectaredB=new ConectaredB();
       Connection conectare=ConectaredB.logareDB();
      PreparedStatement PSMG= null;
     ResultSet RSMG = null;
      String Interogare = "SELECT Admin FROM accounts where Admin='1'";
      try {
          PSMG = conectare.prepareStatement(Interogare);
              PSMG.setLong(1, admin);


          LogareController Adminstatus = new LogareController();

    String Adminstatus = admin.getBytes() //IT only lets me to use getBytes(), i wanted to get the value from admin, after the query executed, this causes a confict with the primitive type "int".

        } catch (Exception exceptie2) {
        return true;

        }
    return false;
         }


}
    }
```

Basically, how do I make a method in which i can save the value of the admin from sql, then when the login credentials are tested to make an "if" condition which will determen what fxml should be loaded.

**LoginVerifier**

```
public class LoginVerifier {



  public LoginVerifier () {


      ConectaredB ConectaredB=new ConectaredB();
        Connection conectare=ConectaredB.logareDB();



   if (conectare == null) {

   System.out.println("Conectare nereusita!");
    System.exit(1);}
  }

  public boolean Conexiune() {
      ConectaredB ConectaredB=new ConectaredB();
        Connection conectare=ConectaredB.logareDB();
   try {
  return !conectare.isClosed();
 } catch (SQLException e) {

  e.printStackTrace();
  return false;
 }

}
  public boolean testaredate(String numeutil, String parola) throws SQLException {
      ConectaredB ConectaredB=new ConectaredB();
        Connection conectare=ConectaredB.logareDB();
      PreparedStatement PSMG= null;
     ResultSet RSMG = null;
      String Interogare = "SELECT * FROM accounts where Username=? and Password=?";
      try {
          PSMG = conectare.prepareStatement(Interogare);
          PSMG.setString(1, numeutil);
          PSMG.setString(2, parola);

          RSMG = PSMG.executeQuery();
            if(RSMG.next()){
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }

        } catch (Exception exceptie2) {
            return false;

        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: "the right way" is to make a DTO (data transfer object) that describes the user (including whether he is an administrator). the login process must initialize and return this object (or return null if input data is incorrect). then simply check the field describing whether the user is an administrator or not.

Comment: I kindof do that in the `LoginVerifier` controller, in which i get everything from the user with the x username and y password, I'm not sure how to get the value that's find in  "admin" tho, and how to use it afterwords. I have pasted the "LoginVerifier"'s code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a rough example of how it can be realized.

The `User` class is a model that describes the user. I've just put them on compatibility with other fx components.

```
public class User {
    private IntegerProperty id = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    private StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private StringProperty password = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private BooleanProperty admin = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

    public int getId() {
        return id.get();
    }

    public IntegerProperty idProperty() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id.set(id);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }

    public StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name.set(name);
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password.get();
    }

    public StringProperty passwordProperty() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password.set(password);
    }

    public boolean isAdmin() {
        return admin.get();
    }

    public BooleanProperty adminProperty() {
        return admin;
    }

    public void setAdmin(boolean admin) {
        this.admin.set(admin);
    }
}
```

The creation and initialization of `User`-class objects is done in the `LoginVerifier#login` function

```
public class LoginVerifier {

    public Optional<User> login(String username, String password) throws SQLException {
        ConectaredB ConectaredB = new ConectaredB();
        Connection conectare = ConectaredB.logareDB();

        PreparedStatement PSMG = null;
        ResultSet RSMG = null;
        String Interogare = "SELECT * FROM accounts where Username = ? and Password = ?";

        PSMG = conectare.prepareStatement(Interogare);
        PSMG.setString(1, username);
        PSMG.setString(2, password);

        RSMG = PSMG.executeQuery();
        if(RSMG.next()) {
            User user = new User();
            user.setName(username);
            user.setPassword(password);
            user.setId(RSMG.getInt("id"));
            user.setAdmin(RSMG.getInt("Admin") == 1);

            return Optional.of(user);
        }

        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

Authentication is done by checking whether `Optional` contains an object or not, and authorizing by checking the `User#isAdmin` property

```
public void Autentificare(ActionEvent event) {
    try {
        Optional<User> optional = loginVerifier.login(Numeutilzator.getText(), Parola.getText());

        if(optional.isPresent()) {
            String fxmlFile = optional.get().isAdmin() ? "/LicentaApp/Meniu_Admin.fxml" : "/LicentaApp/Meniu.fxml";

            Stare.setText("Autentificare reusita !");
            ((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow().hide();

            Stage st = new Stage();
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            Pane Pane = loader.load(getClass().getResource(fxmlFile).openStream());

            Scene scene = new Scene(Pane);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("Style1212.css").toExternalForm());
            st.setScene(scene);
            st.show();
        }
        else {
            Stare.setText("Nume de utilizator sau parola incorect");
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is amazing! I cannot thank you enough, bro, I wanna be capable to do things like this myself so badly, by any chance do you recommend udemy's java course? Cannot post the link to it, its too long, it's called `Complete Java Masterclass` .